# Connecting 2 iDevices via Bluetooth automatically

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

So I don't like how I can connect two iPhones with game kit, because you have to choose the iPhone you want to connect to, the other iPhone has to accept... I think this way sucks. I want to have the Bluetooth ON on my two iDevices and I want them to connect *automatically* between them. Is there a way to do this, or does Apple not approve of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's Bluetooth that won't let this happen.  Check out the options presented here:    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth#Pairing.2FBonding

You can see that only the first SSP option could possibly allow a non-confirmed pairing, and that's not available for devices with security capabilities.